# Apple Development certificate based app on another machine

Tags: macos, apple-developer

wanna deliver my app to our QA .
have signed with Apple Development Certificate . works on my machine but on QA machine it says certificate not valid. MACOS is Catalina .

should Apple development certificate work ?

Comment: Is your dev certificate from a paid Apple Developer account? Is the app archived and notarized? The question is very general but there are some very specific, documented requirements for distributing Mac apps, a paid dev acct and notarization being the main ones. Current reference: https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/

Comment: thankyou Corbell .      the developer certificate is part of paid team account . the app is not archived or notarised. so is notarisation mandatory to run on any other internal machine ?

Comment: Yep, notarization is required for any distributed app under Catalina, and distribution includes just copying to a different machine than where you built it.